# Why must type getline(cin, string) twice?

Tags: c++, user-input, iostream

need your help in getting user inputs.
I want users to type a string that has spaces.
i cant use `cin>>variable` as the space in between makes the problem go wrongly.
if i use `getline(cin,string_variable)` it works correctly. but i need to type twice in order to make it work proberly.

```
cout<<"Enter movie name";
getline(cin, mvName);
getline(cin, mvName);
```

Is there a better way to get user input than this or is there any other codes to type rather than typing the getline twice? Pls advice.

Comment: Do you hit enter to move down from the `"Enter movie name"` question? This would put a blank line into `stdin`, which the first `getline()` would read and then second `getline()` would read your entered text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When switching between formatted input using `in >> value` and unformatted input, e.g., using `std::getline(in, value)` you need to make sure that you have consumed any whitespace you are not interest in. In you case there is probably a newline in the buffer from a prior input. Assuming you are nit interested in leading whitespace the easiest approach is to use something like this:

```
if (std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, mvName)) {
    process(mvName);
}
```

BTW, you should always check that your input was successful.

Comment: OP: "I want users to type a string that has spaces". Maybe OP wants to start from whitespaces, like "   Dog Soldiers    "?

Comment: If the goal is to keep leading spaces it may be necessary to synchronize differently, e.g., ignore everything up to and including the first newline: `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'));` The description is too vague to tell what exactly is needed.

Answer (score 2):

I had no issues using:

`char mvName[32];`

`cin.getline(mvName, 32);`

And I only had to call it once, again with no issues.

Comment: But the next prompt gets displayed automatically and does not allows me to enter for the earlier prompt

Comment: For what ever reason I was unable to recreate the error as described.

Though, my theory is that there's a trailing \r\n in the buffer somewhere that just needs to get flushed out by cin.ignore(256);

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just forget to add `\n` in your prompt message:

```
cout<<"Enter movie name:\n";
```

But if you want skip empty lines - do this:

```
// skip empty lines
while (cin >> mvName && mvName.empty());
// here mvName contains non empty string or it is empty because of error in reading
....
```

Comment: Why does he need a `'\n'` in the prompt message?

Comment: @James See hmjd's answer. This is the reason - human being desire to start typing from new line ;)

Comment: I'm skeptical about this.  If the requested input is a sentence or something, maybe, but it's usual _not_ to go to the start of the next line if the input is something like a name.  (I suspect that Dietmar is on the right track; that he's done input before, and that characters from a previous input are causing the problem.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: OP: "I want users to type a string that has spaces", Anyway let wait for OP answer to hmjd's comment...

Answer (score 1):

As the question contains no new-line character I suspect you hit enter to move down from the `"Enter movie name"` question? This would put a blank line into `stdin`, which the first `getline()` would read and then second `getline()` would read your entered text.

To remove the requirement of typing the initial new-line character just add it to the question's string literal:

```
std::cout<< "Enter movie name:\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cout<<"Enter movie name";
  getline(cin, mvName);
```

Works fine!

Maybe you had to use `getline(cin, mvName);` twice was because you inputted some character into the first `getline(cin, mvName);` like Space, Enter, etc.