# why does the getline() function does not work unless I call it twice in the function charmodifier

Tags: c++, oop, getline

**what's wrong**
if I use the get line function only once in the character modifier function  the compiler will ignore it
unless I call the function twice
why cant I use it only once?
I tried using other ways, it worked but I wanna understand this one
I'm now just writing random things so the add more details error messages go away

````
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class egybest
{
    string link,m;
    char sys, type, restart;
    int s = 1, e = 1, date;
public:
    string charmodifier()
    {
       //here
        getline(cin, m);
        getline(cin, m);
        for (int x = 0; x <= m.size(); x++)
        {
            if (m[x] == ' ')
                m[x] = '-';
        }
        return m;
    }
    ~egybest()
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "do you want to restart the program? y:n;" << endl;
        cin >> restart;
        system("cls");
        if (restart == 'y' || restart == 'Y')
            egybest();
        else if (restart == 'n' || restart == 'N')
        {
            system("exit");
        }
    }
    egybest()
    {
        cout << "do you want to watch a movie or a series? 1:2;" << endl;
        cin >> type;
        system("cls");
        if (type == '1')
            linkmovie();
        else if (type == '2')
            series();
        else
            cout << "wrong input!" << endl;
    }
    void linkmovie()
    {
        cout << "enter the name of the movie:" << endl;
        charmodifier();
        cout << "enter the release date: " << endl;
        cin >> date;
        link = "start https://cape.egybest.cool/movie/" + m + "-" + to_string(date);
        cout << endl;
        system(link.c_str());
    }
    void series()
    {
        cout << "do you want it to open links for a particular season, particular episode or all seasons? s:e:a;"
            << endl;
        cin >> sys;
        system("cls");
        if (sys == 'S' || sys == 's')
            linkseason();
        else if (sys == 'A' || sys == 'a')
            linkall();
        else if (sys == 'E' || sys == 'e')
            linkepisode();
        else
            cout << "wrong input!" << endl;
    }
    void linkall()
    {
        cout << "season No." << endl;
        cin >> s;
        cout << "episode No." << endl;
        cin >> e;
        cout << "enter the name of the show:" << endl;
        charmodifier();
        for (int j = 1; j <= s; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= e; i++)
            {
                link = "start https://cape.egybest.cool/episode/" + m + "-season-" + to_string(j) + "-ep-" + to_string(i);
                system(link.c_str());
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    void linkepisode()
    {
        cout << "season No." << endl;
        cin >> s;
        cout << "episode No." << endl;
        cin >> e;
        cout << "enter the name of the show:" << endl;
        charmodifier();
        link = "start https://cape.egybest.cool/episode/" + m + "-season-" + to_string(s) + "-ep-" + to_string(e);
        cout << endl;
        system(link.c_str());
    }
    void linkseason()
    {
        cout << "season No." << endl;
        cin >> s;
        cout << "episodes No." << endl;
        cin >> e;
        cout << "enter the name of the show:" << endl;
        charmodifier();
        for (int i = 1; i <= e; i++)
        {
            link = "start https://cape.egybest.cool/episode/" + m + "-season-" + to_string(s) + "-ep-" + to_string(i);
            cout << endl;
            system(link.c_str());
        }
    }
};
int main()
{
    egybest egy;
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: [why does std::getline fails after using operator>> twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15662808) and [Why must type getline(cin, string) twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12723648) and many others....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that after entering an integer or a character as for example

```
cout << "episode No." << endl;
cin >> e;
cout << "enter the name of the show:" << endl;
charmodifier();
//...
```

the input buffer contains the new line character `'\n'` that corresponds to the pressed Enter key.

So the following call of `getline` reads an empty string until the new line character is encountered.

In such a case before calling `getline` you need to remove the new line character from the input buffer like for example

```
#include <limits>

//...

cout << "episode No." << endl;
cin >> e;
cout << "enter the name of the show:" << endl;
std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
charmodifier();
//...
```

Comment: thank you sir this is something new to me